# LG + Moto Location checking issues

Tags: android-location, android-workmanager

I work on a location-based app. Seeing some weird trends where LG & Motorola phones on android 9+ (at least) are reporting location off at 2x their usual rates. Samsung has remained flat. This presents a problem as false negatives here create some very negative user experiences. I'm using this to see if the location is on for the device.

```
LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(locationManager)
```

It is not correlated with low battery. Should I just not use this API? Does anyone have insight on this?

Update: Found that this was related to a code release in the app. Moving from Firebase Job Dispatcher to work manager is causing this. On LG & Moto Phones, when WorkManager runs a location check in the background with `battery saver enabled` the call will incorrectly return `false`. I've repro'd this, the solution is not to call this in work manager, but really seems like a deeper bug that lurks somewhere in the depths.